# Setting properties of controls as values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is it right to set properties in XAML as values bymyself? Without bindings or other dependencies. Is WPF smart enough to make the application crossplatform? Will my application seem on another computers like on my computer, even with such strings as Margin = "0,10,10,0" or Height/Width = 566, for example?

Comment: If you will run it on full screen it will depend on resolution of a screen. But generally, it will look the same. It's nothing wrong with hard-coded values in XAML.

Comment: WPF is not cross platform, it works on windows with netframework only. Xamarin would be cross platform. You can set margins or paddings etc with explicit numbers, that is intended. But of course your application might look different on other computers (different resolution, dpi, system-zoom-level, system colors, ...)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean crossplatform, but working on other screens. As I know WPF has different rendering engine, that's because I answer. I thought, that if I set Height="200" on my computer, the Height on the computer with screen, which is twice as much as mine, will be 400. Is it right? @gofal3

Comment: No, if you set Heigh=200 then on a screen that is double of size the Height will be 200 too. But you can use relative size like Heigh=50% too.

Comment: If you work with textboxes, labels, images and so on then the size shall be fixed no mater how big the screen is. then you use absolute sizes. If your application should scale, then use layouting like relative sizes or Container-controls like Grid, Dockingpanel etc that do the sizing for you.

Comment: Thansks) @gofal

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right to set properties in XAML as values by myself?

It's not *MVVM*, and some would say you are circumventing the bind-ability of *WPF*, but it is valid, and no-one can old it against you (much)

> Without bindings or other dependencies. Is WPF smart enough to make the application cross-platform?

If you were able to make *WPF* cross-platform (and I'm not really sure how you would do that (yet)), all else aside it is not *WPF* that would be smart, additionally your bindings would have no bearing or relevance to this question.

> Will my application seem on another computers like on my computer, even with such strings as Margin = "0,10,10,0" or Height/Width = 566,
> for example?

Once again setting *Xaml* properties from *Code-Behind* has the bearing or relevance on how other computers display the *Xaml*.